# Python: how to get the weekday from a CSV?

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I have a sample of CSV which contains various columns and i have to extract the Weekday from the given `date` column. the sample is shown as below:

```
Name,Birthdate,Age,Address
ABC,3-10-2016 11:00:00AM,21,XYZ Street 21 zone
BCD,3-11-2016 15:54:00PM,22,WXY Street 21/A, S zone
CDW,4-11-2015 21:09:00PM,22,ZYX Street 21Avenue, North Zone
```

i want to read the CSV and extract the Date to determine the weekday of the given date column

so far i have created a code to read the CSV and get the weekday but i am unable to implement it on any other CSV.

The code is given below:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime as dt
with open('date.csv', 'r') as f:
  f.readline()

  for line in f:
    date = dt.strptime(line.strip(), '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%A')
    print date
```

please help me here as this is a part of my academic research.

NOTE: In case if the question is not clear then please let me know. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read CSV files, then parse the one column. Since you have a file with headers, it'd be easiest to use the `DictReader()` approach here:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime


with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    for row in reader:
         birthdate = row['Birthdate']  # keys are named in the first row of your CSV
         birthdate = datetime.strptime(birthdate, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
         print birthdate.strftime('%A')
```

Comment: @desmond.carros: sorry, no, I forgot to include the module name there; it is a class the `csv` module provides for you.

Comment: how about if we need to create a new column and add all the days in that new column?

Comment: @desmond.carros: not sure what you are asking here. New problems are perhaps best posted as new questions.

Comment: well to be clear: i want to create a new column and append all the values returned from `print birthdate.strftime('%A')` from your code.

Comment: @desmond.carros: just add another key to the `row` dictionary. `row['Weekday'] = birthdate.strftime('%A')`. You could use a `DictWriter()` object to write that row out to another file again.

Comment: Again, post this as a new question; comments are not really suitable for extended explanations.

Comment: new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938083/python-how-to-add-values-obtained-from-an-operation-in-a-new-column-of-given-cs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106000/discussion-between-desmond-carros-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the `csv` library that you imported as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt        
import csv

with open('date.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        print dt.strptime(row[1], '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S%p').strftime('%A')
```

This would print:

```
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
```

This automatically reads each of your rows in the csv file in as a list of cells. So in this case you access the second column using `row[1]` and pass this to your `strptime` function to get the day of the week.

Comment: this is only a sample. the original data may contain the date column anywhere.

Comment: Assuming you can identify the location using the same header value then the DictReader approach would be best. Otherwise you would need to use a regular expression to try and guess where there data is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime as dt

test_str = open('date.csv').read()
p = re.compile(ur'\w+,(\d+-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+\w{2})')
m = re.findall(p, test_str)
for i in m:
    print dt.strptime(i, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S%p').strftime('%A')
```

Input:

```
Name,Birthdate,Age,Address
ABC,3-10-2016 11:00:00AM,21,XYZ Street 21 zone
BCD,3-11-2016 15:54:00PM,22,WXY Street 21/A, S zone
CDW,4-11-2015 21:09:00PM,22,ZYX Street 21Avenue, North Zone
```

Output:

```
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
```

Comment: nice use of regular expressions. I will use this solution for short codes. Thanks Tim007 :)

Comment: in my original data i have several columns of date though and this regex will intake all the date formats and return days for all the dates. any tweak to control this?

Comment: @desmond.carros Can you post example input?

Comment: **sample** : ID,ID_TYPE,OB_DATE,VERSION_NUM,MET_DOMAIN_NAME,OB_END_CTIME,OB_DAY_CNT,SRC_ID,REC_ST_IND,PRCP_AMT,OB_DAY_CNT_Q,PRCP_AMT_Q,METO_STMP_TIME,MIDAS_STMP_ETIME,PRCP_AMT_J
90, RAIN, 2006-01-01 00:00,1, WADRAIN,900,1,24109,1011,0,0,6, 2006-01-17 09:04,0,

Comment: i want the days for both the dates but in a separate column. also i want to get both of these appended in the same CSV too

Comment: i have started a new post for this also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938083/python-how-to-add-values-obtained-from-an-operation-in-a-new-column-of-given-cs